# How could next.js Link avoid server request?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/navigate-between-pages

> After that, we need to connect these pages. We could use an HTML  tag for that. However, it won't perform client-side navigation; instead the browser will do a request to the server for the next page and refresh the page, which is not what we want.

```
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href="/about">
        <a>About Page</a>
      </Link>
      <p>Hello Next.js</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And later on in their tutorial, it says the above Link mechanism also support browser back button. Why?

> Client-Side History Support When you hit the Back button, it navigates
>   the page to the index page entirely via the client; next/link does all
>   the location.history handling for you.
>
> You don't need to write even a single line of client-side routing
>   code.
>
> Simply link pages; it just works!

Can someone explain why  can make the browser avoid server request? Did next.js somehow made pre-fetching happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link tag has an attribute `prefetch` which is set to **true** by default. when the browser encounters the `Link` tag on the screen, Next js will `prefetch` the JS needed to render the page.

you can set the `prefetch` to **false** if you don't want the pages to be `prefetched`.